# Renaming several ftp files at once

Tags: php, ftp

I have the following sub folders on my ftp under the folder "images":

images1
images2
images3

The reason for this is that I'm using 3 different sizes of each photo I use on my site in news. So in each of the folders are the exact same filenames, only with different sizes of the photos.

What I would like, is to be able to edit the name of the files in an easy and swift fashion.

Say I have a picture called "Car01.jpg" which I'd like to rename "car1.jpg". Then right now I have to go on the ftp and rename each version of the file.

Is there a way or a script out there that can do this for me easily? Re rename all 3 versions? Preferably in php.

So it lists all the images in images1 but when I rename one of the pictures, it changes the name in all 3 folders.

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [FTP protocol wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php):

```
$directories = array('image1', 'image2', 'image3');
$ftpUrls = array_map(function($d) {
   return 'ftp://user:password@server.net/directory/' . $d . '/';
}, $directories);

function rename_all($oldname, $newname, $urls) {
  foreach ($urls as $url) {
    rename($url . $oldname, $url . $newname);
  }
}

// Use like:
rename_all('Car01.jpg', 'car1.jpg', $ftpUrls);
```

Comment: I doubt he need any ftp commands

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Precisely, that's why this answer doesn't use any ;) .